# Trying to install the USB AC-56 Driver

Tags: drivers, asus

I ran `sudo -i` and entered my password. then ran the `install.sh` file and i got this message:

```
root@TiGA:/home/servv/Desktop# bash install.sh
##################################################
Realtek Wi-Fi driver Auto installation script
Novembor, 21 2011 v1.1.0
##################################################
Decompress the driver source tar ball:
    rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux_v4.2.2_7502.20130517.tar.gz

make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-31-generic'
Makefile:1041: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
##################################################
Compile make driver error: 2
Please check error Mesg
##################################################`

The error message is `Makefile:1041: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
##################################################
Compile make driver error: 2
Please check error Mesg
##################################################
```

Can you help me solve this problem? I can boot windows 10 if i need an internet connection.

(I had to remove big parts of the code because Ask Ubuntu thinks "it looks like spam")

Comment: *"(I had to remove big parts of the code because Ask Ubuntu thinks "it looks like spam")"* - Can you please post the entire output on http://paste.ubuntu.com ?

Answer (score 1):

The circa-2011 file you are attempting to compile is far too old to compile on any recent Linux kernel. I suggest that you try this process instead:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux.git
cd ~/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux
sudo make -f Makefile.dkms install
sudo modprobe 8812au
```